# EXC_BAD_ACCESS again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, exc-bad-access

I'm building(trying ... )  an iPhone application.
My first user story is a login View who send the credential of the user to a webservice (WCF).
The communication process with the web service is working fine without any problem.
But I have to deserialize the message coming form it. For that I used the NSXMLParser to create the message Object who contain the response of the service. This when the problem begin :

This is the Message parser :

### .h

```
@interface MessageParser : NSObject  <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableString* currentProperty;
    Message* message;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString* currentProperty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Message* message;

- (void)parseMessageData:(NSData *)data parseError:(NSError **)err;

@end
```

### .m

```
@implementation MessageParser

@synthesize message, currentProperty;

- (void)parseMessageData:(NSData *)data parseError:(NSError **)err 
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [parser setDelegate:self]; 
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; 
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; 
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; 

    [parser parse];

    if (err && [parser parserError]) {
        *err = [parser parserError];
    }

    [parser release];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if(qName){
        elementName = qName;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Message"]){
        self.message = [[Message alloc] init];
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"body"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"code"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"error"]){
        currentProperty = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if(qName){
        elementName = qName;
    }
    if(message){
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"body"]){
            self.message.messageBody = currentProperty;
        }
        else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"error"]){
            self.message.error = currentProperty;
        }
        else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"code"]){

            NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];            
            [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

            self.message.messageCode = [f numberFromString:currentProperty];
            [f release];
        }
    }

    self.currentProperty = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)foundedCharacters
{
    if (self.currentProperty) {
        [currentProperty appendFormat:@"%@", foundedCharacters];
    }
}
```

this is the Login action :

```
- (IBAction)didLogin:(id)sender 
{
    NSData* receivedData;
    NSError* parserError;
    NSError* error;

    receivedData = [[ServiceClient PerformLogin:txtLogin.text withPassword:txtPassword.text error:error] retain];    
    MessageParser* messageParser = [[MessageParser alloc] init];

    Message* msg;    
    [messageParser parseMessageData:receivedData parseError:&parserError];

    msg = [messageParser.message retain];

    if(msg && !msg.error){        

        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Service Response" message:msg.messageBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(msg.error){
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg.error delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(!msg){
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Enable to contact the Athentication service." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

the Message Object :

```
@interface Message : NSObject{
    NSString* messageBody;
    NSNumber* messageCode;
    NSString* error;   
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* messageBody;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber* messageCode;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* error;

@end

@implementation Message
@synthesize error, messageBody, messageCode;

@end
```

So what is happened ? 
Some time when is clik login it show me the alert then xcode throw me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the main.m in this code :

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

And some time when I click login it throw me the same error directly.

What's wrong with my code ? Do I have some memory management problems ? where ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a convenience method without retaining the result....

```
currentProperty = [NSMutableString string];
```

either do...

```
currentProperty = [[NSMutableString string] retain];
```

or seeing as you declare the property with a retain attribute use...

```
self.currentProperty = [NSMutableString string];
```

Also note that the following line is leaking memory....

```
self.message = [[Message alloc] init];
```

as the property also has a retain attribute you need to release the version you create...

```
Message *aMessage = [[Message alloc] init];
self.message = aMessage;
[aMessage release];
```

...or...

```
message = [[Message alloc] init];
```

Comment: They are using ARC do cannot have the retain issues you are referring to. @autorelease pool signifies this.

Comment: They most definitely are NOT using ARC, re-read their code. They have releases all over the place, that isn't using ARC.

Comment: Thank you so much Simon.
I have some knowledge leak too about memory management. Do you have an practical link talking about memory management with Objective-c ?

Comment: I'll dig out some links but start with the Apple guide on memory management (access it via the developer portal). It is quite simple once you start seeing it in the right way, just take a short while to 'get it'.

Comment: You can also use ARC and avoid most of it if using iOS5, however I would advise anyone new to Objective-c to at least look at how to do things manually so you have a better understanding of what the automatic route is doing for you.

Comment: This is really good, read through it as it mixes memory management in with other key concepts, a nice simple explanation.... http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 1):

put `NSZombieEnabled : YES` in your project's "Edit Active Executable" section. I hope it could help to get a trace on the issue.